# Custom WC Ajax Action Not Working in WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I am creating a new custom plugin in WooCommerce. I have to upload a file using ajax from front end so I added following code in my payment gateway class. I want to create a new ajax endpoint in class.

I added following line in constructor.

```
add_action( 'wc_ajax_wc_upload_payment_receipt', array( $this, 'wc_ajax_upload_payment_receipt'));
```

And create following function in class

```
public function wc_ajax_upload_payment_receipt(){
 echo "hi";
 print_r($_REQUEST);
}
```

Now when I call my ajax request using `WC_AJAX::get_endpoint( 'wc_ajax_upload_payment_receipt' )` it is returning nothing.

Why is it not going inside my created function?

Comment: Your actual code, is not testable: *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."***.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your action hook name should not have the same name than the function name…

Woocommerce Classes are case sensitive, so replace wrong `WC_AJAX` by `WC_Ajax` when using the method [`get_endpoint()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_AJAX.html#_get_endpoint):

```
WC_Ajax::get_endpoint( $request );
```

**Related documentation:** [Woocommerce `WC_Ajax` Class source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_AJAX.html)